# Constructing Bent functions of 8 variables

Tags: encryption

I have gone through many literature on bent functions but could not find even a simple examples of creating bent functions. One theorem say like this       If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two bent functions of $V_n$ and $V_m$ them $f(x) \oplus g(x)$ gives bent function of $V_{m+n}$. Can i get any example of creating bent function on V8 by xoring bent function on $V_6$ and $V_2$?   Basically if $V_6$ is having vars $x_1$ to $x_6$ and $V_2$ from $x_1$ to $x_2$ then how we will have function on $V_8$ having $x_1$ to $x_8$. 
Any reference to document which generates bent function with example will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cited the theorem wrong. It is:
If $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are bent, then $f(x) + g(y)$ is bent. The difference is, that the functions are *not* on the same variables. Otherwise you could use $f(x) = g(x)$, and then you get $f(x) + f(x) = 0$, which clearly isn't bent.

By applying above theorem multiple times, this should be bent:
$f(x_1,\dots,x_8) := x_1 x_2 + x_3 x_4 + x_5 x_6 + x_7 x_8$

I would suggest studying [this presentation](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/J.Groth/MesnagerInvited.pdf) by Sihem Mesnager, where sections 5 adresses direct constructions and section 6 adresses secondary constructions (built from other bent functions):

- Slide 30 has explicit direct constructions
- Slide 42 ff. has the above theorem and other constructions from bent functions. Interesting: Slide 44 has a constructions of three bent functions over the same variables.

Comment: Thanks tylo for replying. I have seen only bent functions of one variable x . Say f(x1...xn). Are there bent functions of two variable as you explained above. Are they used in cryptography ?please suggest.

Comment: If you have $x_1$ and $x_2$, that are already two variables. The above presentation is basically about bent functions in cryptography. Nonlinearity is requires in several parts of cryptography, e.g. block ciphers and hash functions. However, bent functions have a problem: They are not balanced, but quite often that is also a requirement. So bent functions are usually not used directly, but they can appear in a larger construction.